# Laravel controller pass HTML element?

Tags: php, laravel, backend

The element I want to pass to view:

```
<option value="UK">UK</option>
<option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
//Something like this...
```

Part of my code:

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
   $output .= '<option value='."$row->Country".'>'.$row->Country.'</option>';
}
```

It will return:

`{"table_data":"German<\/option>Mexico<\/option>Mexico<\/option>UK<\/option>Brazil<\/option>UK<\/option>","total_data":6}`

So, It can only print the name between the , but can not print out the value inside the open tag.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why not just iterate $data to your blade?

Comment: $output .= '<option value='.$row->Country.'>'.$row->Country.'</option>';  will return same result. (delete the double quotes of value property)

Comment: Oh, I should try that... thanks. If I still want to do it this way, how can I do?

Comment: why don't you pass data to blade and writing logic in blade view ?

Answer (score 1):

why not you just do it like this:

in the controller

```
public function country(){
    $countries=Country::all();
    return view('country',compact('countries'));
}
```

in the blade view

```
<select>
  @foreach($contries as $country) 
    <option value="{{$country->name}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Check This In your Controller passing the countries

```
public function country(){
    $countries=Country::all();
    return view('your_blade_file',compact('countries'));
}
```

In your blade option value is $country->id option show it $country->name

```
<select>
  @foreach($contries as $country) 
    <option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```